# C struct within a struct hardcoded initialization

Tags: c, struct, c99, hardcoded

What I am doing wrong here for C99:

```
struct chess {
    struct coordinate {
        char piece;
        int alive;
    } pos[3];
}table[3] =
{
    {
      {'Q', (int)1},{'Q', (int)1},{'Q', (int)1},
      {'B', (int)1},{'B', (int)1},{'B', (int)1},
      {'K', (int)1},{'K', (int)1},{'K', (int)1},
    }
};
```

It gives the error:

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
```

I wish to be able to access the data like having a struct within a struct that:

```
table[row].pos[column].piece
table[row].pos[column].alive
```

I tried several [combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357290/initialize-a-struct-within-a-struct-initialization), and none seems to work for this case. I have done previous struct hard coded initialization before that works, but not a struct within a struct as this time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `piece` is a char, `"Q"` is a string. Use simple quotes.

Comment: Please read your error messages; I'm pretty sure your compiler would have told you it cannot convert a `char *` to a `char`, which would tell you exactly what your problem is.

Comment: And there is no need to cast 1 to int as it is already of that type.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You mean "single"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct chess {
    struct coordinate {
        char piece;
        int alive;
    } pos[3];
} table[3] =
{
    {
        .pos = {{ .piece = 'Q', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'Q', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'Q', .alive = 1 }
               }
    },
    {
        .pos = {{ .piece = 'B', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'B', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'B', .alive = 1 }
               }
    },
    {
        .pos = {{ .piece = 'K', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'K', .alive = 1 },
                { .piece = 'K', .alive = 1 }
               }
    }
};
```

It seems to work. Just be careful about the placement of your braces, and PLEASE try to understand what you are typing. This is how to read the answer :

1. table[3] is an array. So the initializer begin by '{' and ends by '};', with each element separated by a ','
2. each element of this array is a 'struct chess'. So each sub-element begins by '{' and ends by '}'
3. in each 'struct chess' you have an array 'pos[3]'. So another sub-sub '{' and '}'
4. each 'pos' is a struct, so there is sub-sub-sub '{' and '}'
5. finally, the fields are here. [Use the C99 initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) to make your code cleaner. And double quotes in C are char*, not char. Use single-quotes

Advices :

- try to minimize the amount of "difficult-to-read" code. It will serve you
- I never use nested structs. When needed, separate their codes and create function which will initialize them.
- [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language) is useful
- use good variables name and identifiers for your struct. When i read 'pos', I think it is a position on a chess ((x, y) coordinates with informations).

Answer (score 5):

Try to enclose char literals in single quotes as stated above and add extra braces to make inner arrays to be initializer lists.

```
struct chess
{
   struct coordinate
   {
       char piece;
       int alive;
   } pos[3];
}
table[3] =
{  // table of 3 struct chess instances...
   { // ... start of a struct chess with a single member of coordinate[3]...
      { // ... this is where the  coordinate[3] array starts... 
         // ... and those are the individual elements of the  coordinate[3] array
         {'Q', 1}, {'Q', 1}, {'Q', 1}
       }
    },
    {{{'B', 1}, {'B', 1}, {'B', 1}}},
    {{{'K', 1}, {'K', 1}, {'K', 1}}}
};
```

Comment: Can you please advice why is there double `{{}}` around raw?

Comment: Well, I think this is how it works:
    
    table[3] =
        { // init list of table[]
            { // init list of struct chess
                { // init list of pos[]
                   {'Q', 1}, // init list of coordinate
                }
            },

            {{{'B', 1}, {'B', 1}, {'B', 1}}},
            {{{'K', 1}, {'K', 1}, {'K', 1}}}
        };

Check the following url for more examples:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization